# How to pass parameters to setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am relatively novice to javascript. I have written a simple counter program that starts count down from 10 till it reaches 1.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function countDown(secs) {
        var element = document.getElementById("status");
        element.innerHTML = "Please wait for "+secs+" seconds";
        if(secs < 1) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';
            element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
        }
        secs--;
 --->       **var timer = setTimeout('countDown('secs')',1000);**
    }
    </script>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">countDown(10);</script>
```

Then I tried passing parameter as `'+secs+'` to the countDown function.

```
var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+')',1000);
```

Above change works.

My question is why should I need to pass parameter as '+secs+' and NOT only 'secs' ?
What difference does it make?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10313023/1144176)'s a fantastic overview of how to use `setTimeout` properly.

Comment: @JakeStoeffler awesome link !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use

```
var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        countDown(secs)
    },1000);
```

or

```
var timer = setTimeout('countDown('  + secs + ')',1000);
```

In your case the problem was your were using string concatenation with a variable without `+` sign (my second example) with will cause a syntactical error

Comment: user want to pass `secs` variable , so it should be `countDown(secs )`

Comment: Thanks @rab this works. Can you explain or point to some kind of explanation for the same.

Comment: @vijju it that enough

Answer (score 9):

Your first attempt is a synax error:

```
var timer = setTimeout('countDown('secs')',1000);
```

You're trying to pass a string to `setTimeout` (which is a bad idea to begin with), but you're not creating the string properly.

The single quotes around the word `secs` are not escaped, so you're actually passing the string literal `countDown(` followed by the variable `secs`, followed by the string literal `)`.
Because there are no operators between the strings, this is invalid syntax.

However, when you use the `+` symbols, you're adding 3 strings together to create the method invocation you want (*the* `+` *operator is used to concatenate strings in JavaScript*):

```
'countDown(' + 'secs' + ')' ===  'countDown(secs)'
```

The three strings added together create a string that contains valid JavaScript, so it can be passed to the *setTimeout()* function.

Although you *can* pass a string to *setTimeout()*, the better approach is to pass a function reference.

This is typically done with an anonymous function like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    countDown(secs);
}, 1000);
```

If you don't need to pass a parameter, you can do this:

```
function countDown() {
    alert("10... 9... 8...");
}

setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
```

Note that when a function reference is specified as a variable, you do not use the `()` symbols.  When you use parentheses after a function in JavaScript, the function is invoked.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.  Just as an FYI, I always find the MDN documentation to be the best reference for JavaScript.  So.... When I have a question about how _setTimeout()_ works, the first thing I always do is google ["_mdn javascript settimeout_"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Comment: Or rather `settimeout -w3schools` :)

Answer (score 5):

an easy way to do it using setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(FunctionName,delay,arg1,arg2....);
```

In your case you can simply do like that:

```
setTimeout(countDown,1000,secs);
```

I suggest this link: http://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 2):

Aadit had the right idea. I needed to start multiple timeouts within a loop, and they all ended up with the variable set to the same value.
Here is a fiddle illustrating why the only method that works well asynchronously is Aadit's.

http://jsfiddle.net/85fmwew4/

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){bad(i)}, 1000)    // bad for async
    setTimeout(good, 1000, i)               // good for async
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write a closure to perform the decrement like so:

```
if (secs < 1) {
    element.innerHTML = '<h2>Countdown Complete!</h2>';
    element.innerHTML += '<a href="#">Click here now</a>';
} else {
    // wait 1 second
    setTimeout(function() {
        countDown(secs - 1); // decrement and run ourselves again
    }, 1000);
}
```

I've also removed the `clearTimeout()` in favour of a simple `else` condition.

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` function allows you to pass additional parameters to the function. Hence you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
var timer = setTimeout(countDown, 1000, secs);
```

It's supported in all major browsers except for some old versions of IE. See this question for more details: [Why does Underscore.js have a delay function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16890106/783743)

Answer (score 1):

This is the only thing that worked for me (passing variables to setTimeout in node.js):

```
setTimeout(function(teamNum,zeroBase,position) {
    spawnAI(roomIndex, 'scout', teamNum, position);
}, timeToSpawn,teamNum,zeroBase,position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Now with recent javascript optimizations in modern browsers, you can simply do:

`var timer = setTimeout( countDown( secs ) , 1000 );`