# SetTimeout - why is passing a function better then a string?

Tags: javascript

I used

```
setTimeout('InitData()', 100);
```

but JSHint tells me "using a function is better then a string" and I changed it to:

```
setTimeout(function () { InitData() }, 100);
```

But why is it so?

Comment: see heer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080318/how-to-pass-parameters-to-settimeout-function

Comment: The string approach looks like a hack for delayed execution. In JS this is not necessary, because functions are first-class citizens that can be used as function arguments.

Comment: The reason becomes obvious as soon as you start passing arguments.

Comment: Another related question: [Is it bad practice to pass a string to settimeout? If yes, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232574/is-it-bad-practice-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout-if-yes-why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons.

1. Primarily, when you pass `setTimeout` a string, the string is evaluated in the global context. That means that the function it calls has to be a global function. Avoiding globals is good practice.

   For instance, this fails: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/qujila/1) *(see error in the console)*

   ```
   (function() {
      "use strict";

      setTimeout("display('hi');", 0);

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
   })();
   ```

   ...because `display` is not a global function.

   But this works: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/qujila/2)

   ```
   (function() {
     "use strict";

     setTimeout(display.bind(null, 'hi'), 0);
     // Or:
     // setTimeout(function() { display('hi'); }, 0);

     function display(msg) {
       var p = document.createElement('p');
       p.innerHTML = String(msg);
       document.body.appendChild(p);
     }
   })();
   ```
2. Using a function reference rather than a string means we're using the same *semantics* we use just about everywhere else we use callbacks, rather than making calling `setTimeout` some weird special thing. For instance, the way I give `addEventListener` a function to call when an event occurs is the same way I give `setTimeout` a function to call when it times out. Consistent semantics help to avoid errors.
3. Using a function reference rather than a string lets me be very specific about what function I'm calling. Consider:

   ```
   function showInASecond(str) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       alert(str);
     }, 1000);
   }
   ```

   I couldn't reasonably use a string there. Oh, I could try to create a concatenation, being sure to escape everything I'd have to escape in the `str` (like quotes, backslashes, and such), but simple is better.
4. If you pass `setTimeout` a string, it has to fire up a full JavaScript parser to evaluate it. Not much of an issue, but still more work than required.